# How to get first name last name on new Stripe Subscription?

Tags: stripe-payments, salesforce

I've created a process where Stripe information (Customer + Subscription) are synced to Salesforce. In the customer information I only either get the persons name or the company name, but not both.

I would like to get both of these. I've also created custom fields for First Name and Last Name, but they don't get "synced" to the customer record. Is there some way to add this information in either the customer or get the information from the subscription / customer record?

Comment: on `checkout.session.completed` event you can copy your custom fields to the customer's metadata.

Comment: Thanks! Can you do that within Stripe somewhere? Something like AWS Lambda inside Stripe? Otherwise I would need to do the update of customer data from Salesforce.

Comment: You need to create a [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders) endpoint and deploy it yourself.

Comment: Ahh okay, sad. But I'll do it this way then! It seems weird to me that this is not "default". Like is it not clear that I would want first name + last name of a customer even though it's a company? Thanks for the answer!